# Sorting TableView By TimeStamp in Dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm having trouble sorting a tableview by a key in a dictionary. The key is basically a timestamp and I am trying to sort the latest post at the top of my table. I don't know if I have to reload the table again since I have a loop within another loop or if my sorting in the cellForRowAtIndexPath is incorrect. I am seeing the data and it is being sorted as of right now by the first loop (for items in feed). I can't get the entire loop to finish and then sort all by my timestamp key in the dictionary.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
var posts = [Post]()  

func feedPosts(){
    for items in feed{
        let feedId = items["id"] as! String
        ref.queryOrderedByChild("myFeed").queryEqualToValue(“\(feedId)”).observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
            if let snapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {
                for snap in snapshot {
                    if let postDict = snap.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                        let key = snap.key
                        let post = Post(postKey: key, postData: postDict)
                        self.posts.insert(post, atIndex: 0)
                    }
                }
            }
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let post = posts.sort({$0.postedDate > $1.postedDate})[indexPath.row]

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("PostCell") as? FeedPostCell 
    cell.configureCell(post)
    return cell
}
```

**Return Cell**

```
class FeedPostCell: UITableViewCell {

   @IBOutlet var feedTxt: UITextView!
   var post: Post!

   func configureCell(post: Post, img: UIImage? = nil) {
    self.post = post
    self.feedTxt.text = post.feedTxt
    if img != nil {
        self.postImg.image = img
    }
  }
}
```

**DataStructure**

```
-posts
   - postKey
     - myFeed : "123"
     - timestamp: 1472596316060
     - feedTxt: "Here is my feed text"
```

Comment: What does your timestamp string look like?

Comment: Not a solution, but you should sort your posts before you call `tableView.reloadData()`. That way the array won't be sorted every time `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called.

Comment: @JosephQuigley My timestamp is in milliseconds. I use the firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP

Comment: Sorting the array on every pass through cellForRowAtIndexPath is a very, very bad idea. It will make table display appallingly slow (For an O(n•log(n)) sort algorithm, which is about the best you can expect, you'll get O(n^2•log(n) performance, or worse than n^2. A fair number of sort algorithms have n^2 performance in the worst case, meaning that loading your table view would have n^3 performance. Horrible. Plus it means that the order of your data items might change, something that you don't want to happen. Sort your array just before calling `reloadData()` and save the sorted array.

Comment: What does your code do, aside from taking so long to load the table view that it appears to hang?

Comment: @DuncanC it shows the all the data, it just doesn't sort it by my timestamp. Right now it is sorting it by my top for loop, sorting by items in feed.

Comment: So edit your question to show us the definition of your POST object, some sample data, and your configureCell method. Also refactor your code to sort your array just before your call to reloadData and save the sorted array to an instance variable. The sorted array should then be the data source for your table view.

Comment: Since you are using firebase. If  you can copy paste the data-structure in firebase , it would be helpful. Show us how you store data in "myFeed" node.

Answer (score 0):

Your posts should be sorted the way you expect them to, however it looks like you're not assigning anything to the cell. Try something like:

```
cell.postTextLabel.text = post["postStringHere"]
```

Where `cell.postTextLabel` is a UILabel that will contain the text from your post object.

Comment: Presumably that's what the `cell.configureCell(post)` call does. The OP should edit his post to provide that code, as well as the structure of his `Post` object.

Comment: Configure cell wasn't in the revision of the question when I asked, but knowing its body would indeed be helpful

Comment: Oh lordy. That wouldn't work very well now would it?